# vueコマンドが認識されない

Tags: windows-10, vue.js, npm

vue-cliを使ってvueの環境構築をするため、
npmからvue-cliをインストールしたのですが、vueコマンドが認識されずにエラーになってしまいます。

```
npm i -g @vue/cli

vue --version

vue : 用語 'vue' は、コマンドレット、関数、スクリプト ファイル、または操作可能なプログラムの名前として認識されません。
名前が正しく記述されていることを確認し、パスが含まれている場合はそのパスが正しいことを確認してから、再試行してください。
発生場所 行:1 文字:1
+ vue --version
+ ~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (vue:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

vue-cliをインストールした後に環境変数の設定をする必要があるのでしょうか？
教えていただきたいです。

環境はwindows10です。

Answer (score 2):

node.jsのインストーラーを使った場合、デフォルトではインストール時にスクリプトのフォルダがPATHに追加されます。

何かの理由でPATHにない場合は、`npm install -g`でのインストール先を`npm bin -g`で確認し、PATHに追加で解決するはずです。

```
> npm bin -g
C:\Users\foobar\AppData\Roaming\npm
```